# Auto layout: auto update constraints when some view is empty

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view like this

```
 _______________________________
|     |                         |
|  Label 0                      |
|     ^                         |
|  Label 1                      |
|     ^                         |
|  Label 2                      |
|     ^                         |
|  Label N                      |
|_______________________________|
```

`^` stands for a constraint that links the top of `Label X+1` with the bottom of `Label X`. `Label 0` is constrained to the superview's top with a fixed constant.

What I'm trying to achieve is: if some `Label X` is empty, then `Label X+1` has to take its place.

```
 _______________________________
|     |                         |
|  Label 0 (empty)              |
|     ^                         |
|  Label 1                      |
|     ^                         |
|  Label 2                      |
|     ^                         |
|  Label N                      |
|_______________________________|
               |
               |   The new layout
              \ /
 _______________________________
|     |                         |
|  Label 1                      |  (here it is also Label 0 but is empty)
|     ^                         |
|  Label 2                      |
|     ^                         |
|  Label N                      |
|_______________________________|
```

Is this possible with auto layout or do I have to programatically check emptiness to update the constraints manually?

Disclaimer: If this questions sounds very basic excuse me, please, I'm migrating from springs and struts and it is a quite criptic for now.

Comment: You really did nice job forming this question. :) +1 for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to change when content is visible? If not try this: you could do an update in the viewWillAppear method. For each label, call

```
[firstLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
 [firstLabel setText:newProductTitleText];
 [firstLabel sizeToFit];
```

Setting number of lines to 0 lets the label dynamically use an many lines as it needs. If this is an empty label that should actually become 0 lines. This will update the frames and autolayout should take care of the rest.

Comment: The label would have 0 height, but the top margin on the label would still remain.

Comment: IMO This is a bad idea, because it breaks accessibility, I'd use UIStackView as another answer suggests.